How do I make the vertical axis title vertical when I use HIGHCHARTS?
I tried to use two methods to achieve the vertical axis title vertical effect, but the distance between the title and the drawing area is not the length of the title. This makes the distance between the title and the drawing area always changing when I change the title content.How should I set it up so that the title can be arranged vertically while keeping it next to the drawing area?Here are my two examples. https://jsfiddle.net/o5adym8u/;https://jshare.com.cn/edit/public/yxnrxbon#google_vignette
The effect I want is like this picture.

https://i.sstatic.net/jqSKl.png

this is my demo1:https://jsfiddle.net/o5adym8u/

this is my demo2: https://jshare.com.cn/edit/public/yxnrxbon

You can add appropriate writing-mode and text-orientation CSS styles to change the way text is generated. Just set the yAxis.title.useHTML flag to true to apply them to the div in yAxis.title.text.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bpn82Lk5/ 
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.title.useHTML

Thank you very much. In your example, the length of the title is fixed. If I want to change the title to TestTest, the title will be offset to the left. So what should I do to make the title appear near the vertical axis label?

You can try to adjust this using CSS transform property: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dLx1u75m/
